# Can't link facebook to user with parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-3.1

Hi so I set up the facebook sdk and followed all the steps in the parse.com documentation. (https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers/iOS), and when I run the app in my simulator the link opens up in the safari browser and allows me to link the user to their facebook. However, when I put the app on my phone and try to connect the user to their facebook nothing happens. I have checked and permitted access to the facebook app, but it still doesn't work. Has anyone else had this issue? and has there been any solutions?

Comment: It seems like you missed something in the tutorial !

Comment: @RajanBalana I've gone through the documentation over and over and over, and still haven't found any missed steps. Any reason it would work on my simulator, but not my phone?